# Unable to parse the log file using Shell and python

Tags: shell, logging, awk, sed

I am trying to parse the log file using shell or python script. I used awk and sed but no luck. Can some one help me to resolve this. Below is the input and expecting output.

### Input:

```
customer1:123
SRE:1
clientID:1
Error=1
customer1:124
SRE:1
clientID:1
Error=2
customer1:125
SRE:1
clientID:1
Error=3
customer1:126
SRE:1
clientID:1
Error=4
```

### Output:

Customer  |  Error
123             1
124             2
125             3
126             4

Comment: It's not clear which is your input data, and what the desired output looks like.  Can you clean that up and post your failing awk script, and explain what part is not making sense?

Comment: Hi  Ian McGowan, I am sorry, I am newbie to stackover flow. I just cleaned  the input and output. Let me know if its not clear

Comment: Welcome!  You'll find people are a lot more forgiving and willing to help if you put a little effort into making your question easy to understand - if something is not working, show what you've tried, what's not working, and that you've tried to google for it yourself.  Otherwise you'll get "this is not a code writing service" responses.  Re-read this how to ask good questions article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usual to show some of your work, or what you've tried so far, but here's a rough guess at what you're looking for.

```
tmp$ awk -F: '/^customer1:/ {CUST=$2} ; /^Error/ {split($0,a,"=") ; print CUST, a[2]} ' t
```

Or breaking down by line:

```
tmp$ awk -F: '\
> /^customer1:/ {CUST=$2} ; \
> /^Error/ {split($0,a,"=") ; print CUST, a[2]} \
> ' t
123 1
124 2
125 3
126 4
```

The first line

```
/^customer1:/ {CUST=$2} ;
```

Does two things - matches lines that start (^ means start) with customer1, and those lines are automatically split on : because we said -F: at the start of our command.

```
/^Error/ {split($0,a,"=") ; print CUST, a[2]} ;
```

Matches lines that starts with Error, splits those lines into array a, on the delimiter "=", and then prints out the last value of CUST, as well as the second field on the error line.

Hopefully that all makes sense.  It's worth reading an awk tutorial like https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: Any idea, how to add header to the output: Customer | Error
123 1
124 2
125 3
126 4